# Error: Attempt to read from field 'int com.fleetboard.sdk.lib.version.SdkVersion.fmajor' on a null object reference

Tags: android, fleetboard

I am using Android API level 18 for fleetboard application. During vehicle demo application, I got error as mentioned in title. Can anyone one help me?

**Stacktrace**

java.lang.Throwable
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.queueTask(DumbServiceImpl.java:165)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerComponent.doSynchronizeRoots(ProjectRootManagerComponent.java:295)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerImpl.fireRootsChanged(ProjectRootManagerImpl.java:414)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerImpl.access$100(ProjectRootManagerImpl.java:55)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerImpl$BatchSession.fireChange(ProjectRootManagerImpl.java:112)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerImpl$BatchSession.rootsChanged(ProjectRootManagerImpl.java:125)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerImpl.mergeRootsChangesDuring(ProjectRootManagerImpl.java:319)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.util.Projects.lambda$null$5(Projects.java:236)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:898)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.util.Projects.lambda$executeProjectChanges$6(Projects.java:234)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:301)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:795)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:631)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:387)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

**Build.Gradle (app)**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.fleetboard.sdk.demo"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 18
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
}
```

**bundle.gradle(Project)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com"}
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.10' //we want gradle 2.10 to run this project
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**'int com.fleetboard.sdk.lib.version.SdkVersion.fmajor'**

```
//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by Fernflower decompiler)
//

package com.fleetboard.sdk.lib.version;

public class SdkVersion {
    private final int fMajor;
    private final int fMinor;
    private final int fBugfix;
    private final int fBuild;
    private final String fVersionCode;

    public SdkVersion(int major, int minor, int bugfix, int build) {
        this.fMajor = major;
        this.fMinor = minor;
        this.fBugfix = bugfix;
        this.fBuild = build;
        this.fVersionCode = this.fMajor + "." + this.fMinor + "." + this.fBugfix + "." + this.fBuild;
    }

    public boolean isMajorCompatibleTo(SdkVersion other) {
        return this.fMajor == other.fMajor;
    }

    public boolean isMinorCompatibleTo(SdkVersion other) {
        return this.isMajorCompatibleTo(other) && this.fMinor <= other.fMinor;
    }

    public int getMajor() {
        return this.fMajor;
    }

    public int getMinor() {
        return this.fMinor;
    }

    public int getBugfix() {
        return this.fBugfix;
    }

    public int getBuild() {
        return this.fBuild;
    }

    public String getVersionCode() {
        return this.fVersionCode;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        buffer.append("SdkVersion [fMajor=");
        buffer.append(this.fMajor);
        buffer.append(", fMinor=");
        buffer.append(this.fMinor);
        buffer.append(", fBugfix=");
        buffer.append(this.fBugfix);
        buffer.append(", fBuild=");
        buffer.append(this.fBuild);
        buffer.append(", fVersionCode=");
        buffer.append(this.fVersionCode);
        buffer.append("]");
        return buffer.toString();
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        boolean prime = true;
        byte result = 1;
        int result1 = 31 * result + this.fBugfix;
        result1 = 31 * result1 + this.fBuild;
        result1 = 31 * result1 + this.fMajor;
        result1 = 31 * result1 + this.fMinor;
        return result1;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(this == obj) {
            return true;
        } else if(obj == null) {
            return false;
        } else if(this.getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        } else {
            SdkVersion other = (SdkVersion)obj;
            return this.fBugfix != other.fBugfix?false:(this.fBuild != other.fBuild?false:(this.fMajor != other.fMajor?false:this.fMinor == other.fMinor));
        }
    }
}
```

In this file I found one notification: Decompiled.class,bytecode version:50.0(Java 6)... but I am not able to install because of source not found.

Comment: post full stacktrace and related code

Comment: Where do you try to run the demo app? On an emulator?

Comment: yes i am running  it on emulator.. @TobiasAmon

Comment: Hi,
access to the fleetboard apis is only working on fleetboard hardware. After the official launch of the fleetboard store you can register as app developer and borrow a device (DispoPilot Guide).

Comment: Thank you very much for giving valuable response.....@TobiasAmon

Answer (score 0):

we've released the developer portal to the public. You can register as developer/app provider now.

Please go to https://developer.fleetboard.com an click "Do you want to become an app provider?"

The wizard will guide you through the registration process.

Comment: thank you... @Tobias  I will create an Account....I hope I will find my solution...